# ¿Cómo hago operaciones con datos almacenados en archivos de texto en C#, Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, archivo

Necesito almacenar en un archivo de texto, el salario de un usuario y a ese salario tengo que descontarles impuestos, renta y demás, ¿cómo puedo hacer restas a cantidades almacenadas en archivos de texto? Por favor, ayuda.
[image: En la imagen aparece lo que tengo que hacer]

Comment: Saludos Diego, bienvanido, lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Algo asi? No se muy bien lo que quieres.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Proyecto1
{
    class Program
    {
        static String nombreFilchero = "salario.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float salario = 1000;

            writeToFile(salario);

            salario = readFromFile();

            float impuesto = salario * .20f;

            salario -= impuesto;

            writeToFile(salario);
        }

        protected static float readFromFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader readtext = new StreamReader(nombreFilchero))
            {
                string text = readtext.ReadLine();
                return float.Parse(text);
            }
        }

        protected static void writeToFile(float f)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(nombreFilchero))
            {
                writetext.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", f));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, pero en estos casos cuando *no queda claro lo que se pide* evitamos contestar en tanto OP mejora su pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Me parece bien lo que comentas. A veces estas tan perdido que no sabes que preguntar, pero es cierto que la pregunta podia estar mas afinada ;)